# Cannot edit group policy

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy

I keep getting the error message

"Failed to open the Group Policy Object. You may not have appropriate rights. Details: The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted."

When trying to add a group policy on the domain controller.

I'm logging in with my account on the domain but have all administrative privileges available on the server (Windows 2003).

I ran dcdiag and it produced the error: An Error Event occured. EventID: 0xC101003B Event String could not be retrieved

Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You have administrative privileges on the server, or the domain?

Comment: What groups is your user account in?

Comment: should be both. Even logging in with the administrator account on the server will not allow changes.

Comment: My account is in Administrators group, DnsAdmins, Domin Admins, Domain Users

Comment: dcdiag (if this is on a domain controller) or netdiag show any errors?

Comment: yes, dcdiag error is listed above edited into the question. it in the usual windows fashion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Rebooted the server after hours and I'm now able to edit group policies. Simple enough.